# Measure the size of Session Attribute Objects

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, httpsession

I want to measure the size of an object (Serialized or not)  when it is set to HttpSession. How can I do this ?
Even some supporting questions found, it could not be used..  Any one know how I can do this ? Probably, usage of session listener could be valuable.But how to measure the size of the Object ? 
For example

```
session.setAttribute("attrName",sessionObj);
```

How to measure the size of this sessionObj ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [java.lang.instrument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) to measure size of an object.

> This class provides services needed to instrument Java programming
>   language code. Instrumentation is the addition of byte-codes to
>   methods for the purpose of gathering data to be utilized by tools.
>   Since the changes are purely additive, these tools do not modify
>   application state or behavior. Examples of such benign tools include
>   monitoring agents, profilers, coverage analyzers, and event loggers.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object) is an example how to use it.

As you stated, `[HttpSessionAttributeListener][3]` is a good place for checking size of added attributes. 
Add here code for size.

```
public void attributeAdded(ServletContextAttributeEvent scae) {
    System.out.println("Attribute addedd:["+scae.getName()+"],"+scae.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Thanks v much.. but one explanation for Instrumentation. how to culate the size of the object inside the method "getObjectSize()" of Instrumentation ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object